# BSOD after attempt at windows update. Not Random

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windows-update, login-screen

Windows-U-7-sp1 here. A system failure during a windows update locked the Laptop and after an hour had to power it off. When returning to try to boot, i get these bsod errors:

**0x000000f4 0xfffffa800bd76060 0xfffffa800bd76340 0xfffff8004b07130**

I cannot login to even safemode or now to run repairs or get a command line.

I booted with a recovery cd and their were NO system restore points shown. 
Installed Linux on this same machine so could get online and try to find some answers.

Have been trying for 2 days to figure out what file have been corrupted and remove/repair them. SFC will not run.

Did a HDD check and the drive is fine. 
If need more information, will post as it is requested.
Have not used this site before so may fubar about abit until understand it better.
Appreciate the help.
Eddie

ED: I can access the hard drive from this linux install. 
ED: current UTC 05:32
Acer aspire 7741. Unable to figure out how to turn crash reporting on from recovery disk. ie: no .dmp file  :/
Looking thru the dism options as well.

Comment: Do you remember the update you were doing? from what I have read about the first part of the bluescreen its best to do a [clean install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1649-clean-install-windows-7-a.html) But I would hold off on doing that Just yet. In case someone else has some insight. On another note you can find the dump info  here `C:\WINDOWS called MEMORY.DMP` If you could grab it through linux you may be able to find some very useful information.

Comment: Thank you. No do not know what updates were being done as have had them shut off since they caused so much hassles in the past. somehow they were reenabled. I will boot back up and let it bsod, then post what I find. ATM tho, there is nothing in this directory. Not sure if it has been shut off. This is not a viral issue to be sure. Also, checked the %sysroot% and in general did a search for *.dmp. Nothing shown.

Comment: Are your Documents still showing up? If the system is completely not there a Clean install may be your only bet. But if you can find anything useful we could see what caused it in the first place. Could you add the make/Model of your laptop to the post?

Comment: Sure.. The disk is fine. All structures are there and chkdsk ran fine. I rebooted it and let it crash same place as always. windows logo shows, sound activates, mouse pointer shows the it bs. There is no "title" and the numbers have changed abit. For some reason it is not writing the logs/dump files. Am making a windows7 usb boot to see if can figuere out how to turn the crash dump.logging back on from a cli in the dart menu. I believe you are correct that its not worth 5 years of settings and customization to do a fresh instal. Hoping that some drivers/sys files just have become damaged/lost.

Comment: No luck on learning how to turn on crash dumps from a cli. Made a win64 recovery bootdisk that takes straight to console. Attempted to run sfc with both scannow and veriyolnl. result is "Win resource protection could not start repair service". Trying to get past that ATM.

Comment: See this link for the  "Win resource protection could not start repair service" error http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-perform-offline-system-integrity.html

Comment: Thanx for the help. did this and still had same errors. Have fixed it as such.
Deleted all file in winsys after the time had the error. deleted all updates and pending changes. Boots now but still have the sfc error. Still working. Thank you

Comment: Since you can access the hard drive, I would backup and then reformat and reinstall.  That sounds like a nasty crash and you're going to spend a lot more time doing forensics than reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the dumps from C:\Windows\minidump

Use nirsoft bsod viewer BlueScreenView to examine the dumps on another working computer.

However, since this happened during a windows update, it could have been a driver or an SMBus type update, which is severe enough not to generate a dump.

You could be fighting against more than one BSOD-causing issue, so do not sweat it since you are fortunate enough to have a working drive with your data still intact, just a hosed OS...

Since no backups, and the system repair disk has been unsucessful, I highly agree with Dan Whaley above and perform a fresh install of Windows.

You can install Windows into a different directory, get up and running, create your restore points as you go along with your latest windows updates this time, THEN go back and do forensics to your content.

Hope that helps, 
             ClaireW